# D3.js force directed graph, each group different color?

Tags: d3.js, colors, nodes, force-layout

I've made a force directed graph with d3.js plugin, and I wanna color the nodes and the labels with the different color according to group which they belong.

I've added scale for color:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
```

and to node variable I've added:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

but all nodes are in the same color..

Here is my current situation: http://jsfiddle.net/WBkw9/

full script:

```
var links = [
  {source: "John", target: "Mike", group: "5"},
  {source: "John", target: "Janice", group: "5"},
  {source: "John", target: "Caleb", group: "5"},
  {source: "John", target: "Anna", group: "4"},
  {source: "John", target: "Tommy", group: "3"},
  {source: "John", target: "Jack", group: "2"},
  {source: "John", target: "Vilma", group: "1"},
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8);

node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function mouseover() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
}

function mouseout() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);
}
```

what am I missing for different color on each group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `group` is not defined for your data. As a result, all of your nodes are colored for group 'undefined'. Your circles are defined for the data in `force.nodes()`, which have the attributes `index` `name` `px` `py` `weight` `x` and `y`. `group` is only defined for the links, which never have color applied to them.

As it currently stands, there also isn't a clear way to determine what color a node should be. What happens if more than one link connects to a node, and these links are in different groups?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code (based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). It's working perfectly.
You can see how it looks like here : http://jsfiddle.net/Rom2BE/H2PkT/

Each group has a different color.

```
**index.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 650,
    height = 700;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  // You define here your nodes and the color will be d.group
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  //Display node name when mouse on a node
  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  //Where and how nodes are displayed
  force.on("tick", function() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  });

  //Legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});

</script>


**data.json**

{"nodes":[
  {"name":"Vertex 5","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 9","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 15","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-3-53688"},{"name":"Vertex 20","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 26","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 29","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 33","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 37","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 49","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-3-53688"},{"name":"Vertex 52","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 53","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 58","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 59","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 65","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 73","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 74","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 80","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-36095"},{"name":"Vertex 84","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 87","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"},{"name":"Vertex 99","group":"Virtuals-MacBook-Pro-4-40842"}
],
"links":[
  {"source":5,"value":1,"target":11},{"source":5,"value":1,"target":12},{"source":10,"value":1,"target":12},{"source":11,"value":1,"target":5},{"source":11,"value":1,"target":12},{"source":11,"value":1,"target":14},{"source":12,"value":1,"target":5},{"source":12,"value":1,"target":10},{"source":12,"value":1,"target":11},{"source":14,"value":1,"target":11},{"source":16,"value":1,"target":19},{"source":18,"value":1,"target":19},{"source":19,"value":1,"target":16},{"source":19,"value":1,"target":18}
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your group info is only available in the `links` object, like @ckersch already pointed out. You would need to add the group info to you `nodes` object too. For this example that can be done by changing line 16 into:

```js
link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, group: link.group});
```

But for more complex data, with more than one `source`, all sources would have the same colour (or would that be OK?).

I made that change in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WBkw9/19/.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the style attribute of the circle, not the `g` element.

```
node.append("circle").style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

Edit: The group property in the data must also be changed integers, or cast later.

Comment: this just changes colouring in that way so only node is coloured and not the text altogether. But still this does not solves my problem, http://jsfiddle.net/F2fbu/ . I wanna get every group colored differently, now seems to me that I can not do this with that kind of data because I need specify which group is what node...

Comment: The group must be an integer, not a string. `d3.selectAll("circle").style("fill", function(d) { return color(9)})` changed the color of all circles.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever solve this? if not a possible solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/adeaver/F2fbu/1/

Each group/node is differently colored along with the corresponding text by adding:
    `.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })`
to the text append and `group: link.group` to the function that computes the nodes from the links