# d3.js - Collapsible Force Layout - setting variable colors to leaf nodes

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js

I have been working with this template of d3.js - Collapsible Force Layout diagram: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

Is there any way the leaf nodes of different branches could have different colors?

My guess is that it can be achieved by modifying "function color(d) {}" and assigning different colors to children with different group numbers. Then adding group numbers to children in json. file. ? I might also be wrong.

```
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
     : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
     : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}
```

My knowledge of JavaScripts does not let me figure out the code myself.

Any kind of help from a good programming soul will be much appreciated.

For illustration this is what i'm looking for:

[Different leaf node color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V40c.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the color function has to be changed.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837463/d3-js-force-directed-graph-each-group-different-color) shows how to assign a unique color to records based on one of their attributes. Read also: [d3.js ordinal scales reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales).

My understanding is that you want all the nodes to be colored based on their parents. Here is how to do it.

#### Adapting the data source

For each node, you want to know which parent it has. This will allow you to give a color to each node, based on its parent.

For example, data could look like this (excerpt):

```
{
 "name": "optimization",
 "parentName": "analytics", 
 "children": [
  {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "parentName": "optimization", "size": 7074}
 ]
}
```

For each node, `parentName` tells you how the group of the record.

This information is missing in the gist you linked, you could process it by traversing the tree and attaching the `parentName` information on the fly.

#### Color scale

An easy way to get colors that can be assigned to groups is to use the categorical color scales built-in d3.js, for example [category10](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10).

```
var nodeColor = d3.scale.category10();
```

#### Assigning color to each record

The `color` function should be modified in order to assign a color based on the node's `parentName` property:

```
function color(d) {
  return nodeColor(d.parentName)
}
```

You will note that I have modified the function to dynamically assign a color not only to the leaves, but also to the nodes at all levels. This is not compulsory, but I did so to avoid collision between `category10` colors, and the hard-coded colors of the gist, which may have looked confusing.

Here is a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5bSAJfeG0c4XVmhl7X3C?p=preview) (fork of the original gist).

#### Alernatives / variants

You may adapt the code above to assign colors chosen by you for each specific group, using ordinal scale instead of `category10`.

```
var nodeColor = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['none', 'flare', 'analytics', 'graph', 'cluster', 'optimization'])
  .range(['black', '#ffaa00', 'grey', 'red', 'green', 'blue'])
```

This is illustrated [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PtRThM0wAk2bawlmUOAE?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much mef!!! I managed to get different colors to my leaf nodes now according to "var nodeColor = d3.scale.category10();" from your working demo. It gave me random colors though (purple and orange and red). Is there a possibility to chose between the colors? And one off-topic question: Is there a way to make the text of leaf nodes a bit smaller? I might ask a separate proper question if you think this is too off-topic. I'm genuinely thankful to you!

Comment: the choice between colors was explained in the "alternatives / variants" part of the answer, I have updated it to include a concrete demonstation of how to do it. For the text nodes size you should ask a separate question.

Comment: thank you very much mef! i really appreciate your help. have a good day.