# D3 - company server network - what type of graph to use?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We have 2-column spreadsheet of all company servers that talk to one other daily:

```
Server,Client
sql1,web1  
sql1,web2  
sql2,web2  
sql2,sql1  
sql2,web3  
web2,app1
```

I tried plotting this using [force-directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532662/d3-create-network-graph-from-2-column-list-of-nodes), but the number of servers & connections is so high that it is a mess of overlapping lines when displayed.

I'd like a spread-out & static graph, that is also search-able (highlights a server and its connections when searched).

I'm looking for graph similar to this - https://linkedjazz.org/network/?mode=wave
What D3 graph type should I use ?

Comment: How about [this](https://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/13/visualizing-a-network-with-cypher/) (from [the big list of d3.js examples](http://christopheviau.com/d3list/))?

Comment: thanks.. however that looks suited to hierarchical/tree connections.. but we have lot of inter-node links between database servers i.e not many parent-child relationships.. i'm looking for one similar but simpler to this - https://linkedjazz.org/network/?mode=wave , but it's source is too complex